# Identify this website theme

Tags: website-design, website-templates

http://www.proxybase.org

Can someone help me identify what this website theme is? I have seen it a couple of times on other websites as well.

Comment: if you know how to use `wget` you can pull the theme files to examine how it was created.

Comment: Not sure which one that is, but I'd call it 'ugly'.

Comment: Doesn't look like a template to me...no obvious markers in the source code. @graphicsman, I'm not familiar with wget! Might be worth an answer if this question is determined to be in GD.SE's scope (admittedly, this question might do better in Webmasters).

Comment: `wget` is terminal based and questions are best on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since it has been answered and commented, closing as off-topic. Danny, if you have any other questions regarding design, please feel free to ask them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about that particular one, because it's not signed (which makes me think it's either custom-made or "taken"), but if you are using WP [you can find some similar free ones here](http://wpthemes.co.nz/category/free-themes/), or doing a search for free WP themes.

Even the WP default theme looks similar to that once you edit some small things (you can add the black details in your custom.css file).

Comment: Yeah I concluded to the same thing but it looked a lot like it was a theme since I saw it again somewhere else. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My guess is someone designed it based on one of those other themes, otherwise there should be some info in the head or the css.